# Poles at infinity of $\log(z^2-1)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Background: This is from MIT OCW 18.04. According to the document, f has a branch point at $z-\infty$.

$$\begin{aligned}z &= \frac{1}{t}\\
 \log(z^2-1)&=\log(1-2t^2)-2\log(t) \end{aligned}$$ The point t=0 is thus a branch point when $|t|<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. How does $1-\color{red}{2}t^2$ correspond to the branch points at $z=\pm1$, as would be expected? Why does the the branch point at t=0 correspond to $z-\infty$ and not $\infty$?

Nevermind about question 1. I'm just going to assume the 2 is a typo unless someone says otherwise.

Comment: What does "at $z-\infty$" mean? Does it mean, "at $z=-\infty$"?

Comment: And where does $1-2t^2$ come from? Shouldn't it be $1-t^2$?

Comment: That's what's confusing me

Comment: I'm not very impressed with mit's course so far, nor with churchill's book nor saff, snider's half way through each. IMO were a waste of time but the books that are interesting to read don't have enough solutions to the problems worked out Ablowitz, bak, boas).

Comment: So is there a way to communicate with MIT to ask them these questions?

Comment: Surprisingly, some of the answers I read here are better than textbooks unfortunately I don't have the time to latex every question I have that. One of the worst professors I had, that did not seem intelligent at all compared to the good ones is the author of dozens of books that appear at the top of every course list from complex analysis to nonlinear PDE. I always skip his books b/c I know whatever he wrote i doubt be really understood.